# ¿Puedo usar más de un Join en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT modulos.cmod, descripcio, nota.cmod cursada,noms
FROM modulos, alumno
LEFT JOIN nota ON nota.cmod = modulos.cmod AND nota.codigo = *****
WHERE modulos.carrera = "C" AND activo = 1
HAVING cursada IS NULL
```

Con la consulta quiero obtener los nombres(noms) que se encuentran en la tabla de alumno, pero no se si tengo que poner algo más en la sentencia del join

Comment: estas seguro que tu `statement`es tal cual como lo compartiste?

Comment: Obviamente, la respuesta es que sí es posible. Pero sin que compartas mas detalles sobre tus tablas y algunos datos de ejemplo, no es posible decir si tu consulta es correcta o no.

Answer (score 0):

Si, puedes usar mas que un JOIN en una consulta `SQL`. Simplemente lo pones en fila. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... ON <condición> INNER JOIN ... ON <condición2>
INNER JOIN ... ON <condición3> WHERE <condición4>;
```

es perfectamente valido.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, entonces no hay ningún problema si hay un left join con un inner join?

Comment: La BBDD no se va molestar, pero te recomiendo tener aspirina en la casa ( o medicinas mas naturales ) si haces queries con muchos `JOIN` que ademas son de distintos tipos. Es bueno de tener un `UML` de tu BBDD a mano. :)